# ViewPager inside recyclerview not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

In my application i wanted to have a `ViewPager` as row of a `RecyclerView`.This is what i have done but the output is not desired.When i scroll the list the ViewPager is showing invalid data.

RecyclerView Code

```
private Context context;
    private List<ViewPagerModel> listVP;
    private HashMap<Integer, List<ViewPagerModel>> hmList;
    private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;


    public  ListViewPagerAdapter(Context context, HashMap<Integer, List<ViewPagerModel>> hmList, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.hmList = hmList;
        this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public LVPHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_with_viewpager_row, parent, false);
        LVPHolder holder = new LVPHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LVPHolder holder, int position) {

        listVP = hmList.get(position);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter((fragmentActivity).getSupportFragmentManager(), context, listVP);
        holder.viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        holder.circleIndicator.setViewPager(holder.viewPager);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    public class LVPHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ViewPager viewPager=null;
        private CircleIndicator circleIndicator;

        public LVPHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(null);
            circleIndicator = (CircleIndicator) itemView.findViewById(R.id.indicator_custom);
        }
    }
```

ViewPager Code

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<ViewPagerModel> listVP;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, List<ViewPagerModel> listVP) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.listVP = listVP;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        Fragment fragment = VPFragment.newInstance(position);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator_custom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:ci_animator="@animator/indicator_animator"
        app:ci_animator_reverse="@animator/indicator_animator_reverse"
        app:ci_drawable="@drawable/black_radius_square"
        app:ci_height="4dp"
        app:ci_margin="6dp"
        app:ci_width="10dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare `listVP` and `viewPagerAdapter` as class variable.

Remove:

```
private List<ViewPagerModel> listVP;
private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
```

And change your code like that:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LVPHolder holder, int position) {

        List<ViewPagerModel> listVP = hmList.get(position);
        ViewPagerAdapter  viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter((fragmentActivity).getSupportFragmentManager(), context, listVP);
        holder.viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        holder.circleIndicator.setViewPager(holder.viewPager);    
    }
```

Comment: sorry but how can u take viewpager adapter into a HashMap

Comment: What you mean by "*the output is not desired*"? can you post a screenshot for your problem?

Comment: When i scroll the list diffrent rows are getting selected